# The body might complete normally, causing null to be returned

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I fix this code. I think i have to put return value but to where. Any help?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
          10.0,
        ),
        child: FutureBuilder<Categories>(
          future: _futureCategories,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Categories> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final name = snapshot.data?.data;
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: name!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return DefaultTabController(
                      length: name.length,
                      child: Scaffold(
                        appBar: AppBar(
                          bottom: const TabBar(
                            tabs: [
                              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return NewsError(
                errorMessage: '${snapshot.hasError}',
              );
            } else {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
```

Widget build underline is red. When I put under Widget line

```
return Container(
```

the error disappaer but I see only blank black screen when I execute the code

Comment: use return Container();  besides can you explain add more clarifications

Comment: FutureBuilder and rest becoming Dead Code

Comment: I would remove the last } else { clause to return the circular progress indicator white it doesn't a value

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `return` before `Container`.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return  Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
          10.0,
        ),
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _futureCategories(),
```

Does it solve ?

Comment: this return fixing the error but this time the screen goes completely blank

Comment: also, assign future like `   future: _futureCategories(),` and make sure you `@override` over build

Comment: future: _futureCategories(), causing error: The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.

Comment: here is the final code there is no error but emulator screen is completely blank
https://monosnap.com/file/edFHLxpVUqwDuUxKcjuuT3c4Qlw3ZZ

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the last part in else, just return it without using else, and also return Container, like this:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return 
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
              10.0,
            ),
            child: FutureBuilder<Categories>(
              future: _futureCategories,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Categories> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final name = snapshot.data?.data;
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: name!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return DefaultTabController(
                          length: name.length,
                          child: Scaffold(
                            appBar: AppBar(
                              bottom: const TabBar(
                                tabs: [
                                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return NewsError(
                    errorMessage: '${snapshot.hasError}',
                  );
                } 
                 return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                
              },
```

Comment: build is still red

Comment: I think Yeasin Sheikh is right, I edited my answer based on that.